# Upgrading Hibernate 3.6 to 4.3 getting com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am upgrading my legacy application from Hibernate 3.6 to 4.3. The application works fine with Hibernate 3.6. However after I upgraded application to Hibernate 4.3 I am experiencing com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.

The mapping configuration of these entities in the application has not undergone any change and is same as before. Neither the database table in question has changed. So I am unable to realize what is going wrong now. The application is using Spring 4.1 and Java 8 and MS SQL 2014 is the database.

I googled about this error and people seem to suggest that this type of issue happens in case many to one relationship is missing hbm file. However I do not see this in by configuration below

```
<class name="com.mycompany.rm.pmech.common.domain.AdditionalFee"
       table="AdditionalFee">
    <id name="id" column="AdditionalFeeId" type="int">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="station" column="stationId" class="com.mycompany.rm.pmech.common.domain.Station" />
    <many-to-one name="carGroup" column="carGroupId" class="com.mycompany.rm.pmech.common.domain.CarGroup" />
    <property name="effectiveDate" column="EffectiveDate" />
    <property name="feeType" column="FeeType" type="com.mycompany.rm.pmech.common.hibernate.types.HibernateFeeType"/>
    <property name="feeAmount" column="FeeAmount" type="com.mycompany.rm.common.types.DecimalUserType" />
    <property name="feeCalculationType" column="FeeUnit" type="com.mycompany.rm.pmech.common.hibernate.types.HibernateFeeCalculationType" />
    <property name="taxable" column="taxable" type="boolean" />
</class>
```

And here is how my table looks

```
CREATE TABLE [[AdditionalFee](
            [AdditionalFeeId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [CarGroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
            [StationId] [int] NOT NULL,
            [EffectiveDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
            [FeeType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
            [FeeUnit] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
            [FeeAmount] [money] NOT NULL,
            [Taxable] [bit] NOT NULL,
)
```

This is same configuration and table that was used before and worked fine with hibernate 3.6 so I am not suspecting it to be relationship mapping to be the issue.

Below is the code where exception is thrown when saving the entity.

```
getHibernateTemplate().save(additionalFee);
```

Following is the stacktrace of the exception.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:167)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:343)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:308)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:617)
            at com.mycompany.rm.pmech.common.dao.GenericDAO.save(GenericDAO.java:378)
            at com.mycompany.rm.pmech.common.domain.AdditionalChargesCalculatorTest.setupStation(AdditionalChargesCalculatorTest.java:1705)
            at com.mycompany.rm.pmech.common.domain.AdditionalChargesCalculatorTest.onSetUp(AdditionalChargesCalculatorTest.java:1569)
            at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.setUp(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:104)
            at org.springframework.test.ConditionalTestCase.runBare(ConditionalTestCase.java:79)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
            at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
            at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
            at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
            at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
            at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:135)
            at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
            at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
            at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
            at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
            at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
            at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:621)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:617)
            at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:340)
            ... 24 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:390)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:340)
           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:308)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
            ... 48 more
```

Any help/pointers to help resolve the issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, finally managed to solve it: 
Under hibernate3 I made for my enumType (Sex) a special enumType. When migrating to hibernate4 it seems that wasn't necessary anymore, so I removed it. Everything worked fine however in a very special case, I received the message from sql server that data would be truncated.

With SQL Profiler (probably installed with your sql server) I managed to see what is actually sent to the DB and saw that the value for my enum type was too long. I then changed my hibernate mapping from

```
    <property name="sex" column="SEX"/>
```

to

```
    <property name="sex" column="SEX">
        <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
            <param name="enumClass">ch.in4medicine.e4med.common.Sex</param>
        </type>
    </property>
```

and everything works again (for the moment).

So two hints from my side:

- use SQL Profiler to see what is actually sent to DB
- check if you have mapped your enums correctly.